# Using PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager with proxy

Tags: .net-core, sharepoint-online

In my .net-core application, I am using the PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager to connect to Sharepoint Online like this:

```
private void Connect(string user, SecureString pwd, string url)
{
  using AuthenticationManager authManager = new AuthenticationManager(user, pwd);
  using ClientContext context = authManager.GetContext(url);
  // ...
}
```

Since I am behind a proxy I need AuthenticationManager to use that but I couldn't figure out how to do it. PnP uses Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager internally so maybe there is a way to setup a proxy?

Comment: Maybe you can try to fix the default proxy before connecting ? Smth like `HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy("....");`

Comment: @Steve B Thanks - That did it! I was on .NET Standard 2.1 before so I did not see that property before upgrading to .Core 6.0.